# How to Bind a List<object> to DataGrid using MVVM at Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm, datagrid

All, I have an View model that is bound to a `DataGrid` using MVVM.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Resources}">...</DataGrid>
```

Where

```
public ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> Resources { get; private set; }
```

in the `ResourceViewModel` class I have the following properties

```
public string ResourceName
{
    get { return this.resource.ResourceName; }
    set { 
        ...
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<string> ResourceStringList
{
    get { return this.resource.ResourceStringList; }
    set {
        ...
    }
}
```

All properties are displayed in the `DataGrid` but the `ResourceStringList` colletion is being displayed as '(Collection)'.

How can I get the `DataGrid` to display each of the strings contained in the `ResourceStringList` in its own column?

Thanks very much for your time.

---

*Edit. I have implemented the suggestion by @Marc below. I now have the following screenshot to illustrate what I now require:*

[image: ResourceStudio]

*The blank column before my resources column index 3 (zero indexed) is not required, **how do I remove this column?**.*

*I would also like to know **how to add column names to my resource columns?** Perhaps I can just add a `Binding` to `Header` property of the `SeedColumn`.*

Again thanks for your time.

Comment: Why does it have to be separate column? Why can't it be `ItemsControl` in one column with horizontal `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanel` that will look like you have separate, editable columns?

Comment: It makes it easier to do what I want and I am not familiar with the approach you are suggesting. Can you provide an example of how I could do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Ok then, is it fixed number of columns? What would be in these columns? Will they have headers and if yes then do they need to in specific order?

Comment: No, the number of columns is fixed at run-time. The columns would contain strings only at this point. I would like them to have headers to differentiate them but at this stage I have not thought about this aspect. Thanks for your time...

Comment: @Killercam I'm glad you got it up and running so far. I've edited my answer to refer to your questions and I've uploaded my sample project. I hope, the header solution works for you?

Comment: I will award you the bounty in 12hours.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it does the trick for you. I'll get a coffee...

Comment: @Marc, I have another minor issue. I wondered if you would be so kind as to have a quick look if I upload my source code? I appreciate I could be taking advantage here and do not mean to be rude. I understand if you are too busy to do this. The problem is relatively minor, and I am sure you would spot my error right away - basically the `protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged` event is causing the same columns to be added more than once each time a new resource file is loaded in to a new TabControl... Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Killercam: Allright, I'll have a look at it...

Comment: [SkyDriveDownload](http://sdrv.ms/17qLrep) I really appreciate this and wish I had given you some more rep. I am finding learning WPF on my own really tough - I don't know why, but I really appreciate your time. In the folder you will find two .zip files, one with the source code, the other with some .resx files. If you run the project and `File > Load Resource...` and load one of the resource files in the `ResourceResxFiles.zip` it works fine. If you load another, you will see the resource columns are loaded multiple times and each time the tab changes it is added to...

Comment: @Killercam: The grid didn't behave correctly when the ItemsSource was reset, and the TabControl only contains one Grid, which is kind of recycled, which means that every time you cahnge the tab page, the grid you see is the same, but the ItemsSource is switched. I fixed it and checked performance. The column removing and adding is around 1ms, so no big deal. And I got an exception when loading the resource file, I had to add a line to check whether the entry 'fileName' already exists as a key in the dictionary (forgot the name). Just for you to know...

Comment: And no worries, learning WPF is damn hard, especially if you're teaching yourself. I did it the same way and it took months, honestly...

Comment: Forgot: I've uploaded the fixed project to your skydrive...

Comment: Thanks very much @Marc. I can't thank you enough...

Comment: Very welcome, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A datagrid is usually used to display a list of items of the same type with a fixed set of properties per item where each column is one property. So each row is one item, each column is one property on the item. You're case is different, as there is no fixed set of properties but a collection you want to show as if it were a fixed set of a number of properties.

The way to go greatly depends on whether you only want to display the data or whether you want to allow the user to manipulate the data. While the first can be achieved relatively easy using value converters, the latter requires a little more coding to extend the DataGrid class to allow for this behavior. The solutions I show are two of a thousand possibilities and probably not the most elegant ones. That being said, I will describe both ways and start with the two-way version.

**TWO-WAY BINDING (ALLOWS EDITING)**

[The sample project (100KB)](http://www.einmb.de/GridSample.zip)

I created a custom `DataGrid` and a custom 'DataGridColumn', called 'SeedColumn'. `SeedColumn` works just as a textcolumn, but has a property `CollectionName`. The `DataGrid` will add one new text column per item in the collection you've specified in `CollectionName` on the right hand side of the seed column. The seed column only works as a kind of placeholder to tell the DataGrid where to insert which columns. You could use multiple Seedcolumns in one grid.

The Grid and the column classes:

```
public class HorizontalGrid : DataGrid
{
    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        foreach (var seed in Columns.OfType<SeedColumn>().ToList())
        { 
            var seedColumnIndex = Columns.IndexOf(seed) + 1;
            var collectionName = seed.CollectionName;
            var headers = seed.Headers;

            // Check if ItemsSource is IEnumerable<object>
            var data = ItemsSource as IEnumerable<object>;
            if (data == null) return;

            // Copy to list to allow for multiple iterations
            var dataList = data.ToList();
            var collections = dataList.Select(d => GetCollection(collectionName, d));
            var maxItems = collections.Max(c => c.Count());

            for (var i = 0; i < maxItems; i++)
            {
                var header = GetHeader(headers, i);
                var columnBinding = new Binding(string.Format("{0}[{1}]" , seed.CollectionName , i));
                Columns.Insert(seedColumnIndex + i, new DataGridTextColumn {Binding = columnBinding, Header = header});
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetHeader(IList<string> headerList, int index)
    {
        var listIndex = index % headerList.Count;
        return headerList[listIndex];
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> GetCollection(string collectionName, object collectionHolder)
    {
        // Reflect the property which holds the collection
        var propertyInfo = collectionHolder.GetType().GetProperty(collectionName);
        // Get the property value of the property on the collection holder
        var propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(collectionHolder, null);
        // Cast the value
        var collection = propertyValue as IEnumerable<object>;
        return collection;
    }
}

public class SeedColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CollectionNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CollectionName", typeof (string), typeof (SeedColumn), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeadersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Headers", typeof (List<string>), typeof (SeedColumn), new PropertyMetadata(default(List<string>)));

    public List<string> Headers
    {
        get { return (List<string>) GetValue(HeadersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeadersProperty, value); }
    }

    public string CollectionName
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(CollectionNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CollectionNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public SeedColumn()
    {
        Headers = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:loc="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sample="clr-namespace:Sample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <sample:HorizontalGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <sample:HorizontalGrid.Columns>
                <sample:SeedColumn CollectionName="Strings" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <sample:SeedColumn.Headers>
                        <system:String>Header1</system:String>
                        <system:String>Header2</system:String>
                        <system:String>Header3</system:String>
                        <system:String>Header4</system:String>
                    </sample:SeedColumn.Headers>
                </sample:SeedColumn>
            </sample:HorizontalGrid.Columns>
        </sample:HorizontalGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the ViewModels I've used for testing:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> Resources { get; private set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Resources = new ObservableCollection<ResourceViewModel> {new ResourceViewModel(), new ResourceViewModel(), new ResourceViewModel()};
    }
}

public class ResourceViewModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; private set; }

    public ResourceViewModel()
    {
        Name = "Resource";
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string> {"s1", "s2", "s3"};
    }
}
```

and the look (old version without headers):

[image: custom grid]

> **ADDENDUM:**
>
> Regarding the new questions and your comment:
>
> The **NullReferenceException** can have several reasons, but you've obviously
>   solved it. However, the line where it occured is a bit of spaghetti
>   code and I wouldn't do it like this in production code. You need to
>   handle the things that can go wrong in any case... I've modified the
>   code and refactored the line into its own method. This will give you
>   an idea of what's going on, when the exception is thrown.
>
> The **empty column** that you see is the seed column, which is obviously not bound to anything. My idea was to use this column as a kind of row
>   header and bind it to the `Name` of the resource. If you don't need
>   the seedcolumn at all, just set its `Visibility` to collapsed.
>
> ```
> <loc:SeedColumn CollectionName="Strings" Visibility="Collapsed">
> ```
>
> Adding **column headers** is not difficult, but you need to think
>   about where you want to take the from. As you store all your strings
>   in a list, they are just strings, so not related to a second string
>   which you could use as a header. I've implemented a way to sepcify the
>   columns purely in XAML, which might be enough for you for now: You can
>   use it like this:
>
> ```
> <loc:HorizontalGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Resources}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
>     <loc:HorizontalGrid.Columns>
>         <loc:SeedColumn CollectionName="Strings" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Visibility="Collapsed">
>             <loc:SeedColumn.Headers>
>                 <system:String>Header1</system:String>
>                 <system:String>Header2</system:String>
>                 <system:String>Header3</system:String>
>                 <system:String>Header4</system:String>
>             </loc:SeedColumn.Headers>
>         </loc:SeedColumn>
>     </loc:HorizontalGrid.Columns>
> </loc:HorizontalGrid>
> ```
>
> If you have more elements in the collection than headers specified,
>   the column headers will be repeated "Header3", "Header4", "Header1",..
>   The implementation is straight forward. Note that the `Headers` property 
>   of the seed column is bindable as well, you can bind it to any List.

**ONE-WAY BINDING (NO EDITING OF THE DATA)**

A straight-forward way is to implement a converter which formats your data in a table and returns a view on this table to which the DataGrid can be bound. The disadvantage: It does not allow editing the strings, because once the table is created from the original data source, no logical connection between the displayed data and the original data exists. Still, changes on the collection are reflected in the UI, as WPF performs the conversion every time the data source changes. In short: This solution is perfectly fine if you only want to display the data.

How does it work

- Create a custom value converter class, which implements `IValueConverter`
- Create an instance of this class in your XAML resources and give it a name
- Bind the grid's `ItemsSource` with this converter

This is how it would look like (my IDE is StackOverflow, so please check and correct, if necessary):

```
public class ResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var resources = value as IEnumerable<ResourceViewModel>;
        if (resources== null) return null;

        // Better play safe and serach for the max count of all items
        var columns = resources[0].ResourceStringList.Count;

        var t = new DataTable();
        t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ResourceName"));

        for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            // Will create headers "0", "1", "2", etc. for strings
            t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(c.ToString()));
        }

        foreach (var r in resources)
        {
            var newRow = t.NewRow();

            newRow[0] = resources.ResourceName;

            for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++)
            {
                newRow[c+1] = r.ResourceStringList[c];
            }

            t.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }


        return t.DefaultView;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then define a resource in your XAML like this, where loc is your namespace:

```
<loc:ResourceConverter x:Key="Converter" />
```

and then use it like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Resources, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
```

Comment: +1 Thanks very much for your time @Marc. If I wanted to include headers for each of the columns, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: This is _not_ doing what I want. It is adding the resources at the zero indexed position, in a single column as a list. I want each element of the `List` to be displayed in its own column.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I misunderstood what you are trying to do... I'll update my answer..

Comment: Again, thanks for your time. I am pretty new to WPF and had to implement your answer before I fully understood what it would do. Looking at my comment above it looks slightly terse, I did not mean to sound rude. I apologise if it did. again, thanks for your help...

Comment: @Killercam: No problem, sorry for that, I should have read better... Before I get it wrong again: Is two-way binding a requirement, i.e. is the data grid only for displaying or also for editing?

Comment: Yes, ideally I need to be able to edit the rows... Again thanks for your time. I will implement this at lunch as it is my own work.

Comment: I will reward you with some rep :]

Comment: Just implementing this now. I am getting a null reference exception on the line `List<object> collectionItems = ((IEnumerable<object>)dataList[0].GetType().GetProperty(item.CollectionName).GetValue(dataList[0])).ToList();` and it is not clear to me why. I have implemented what you have described but I have changed the names. I am such a noob that I am confused as to why this is occurring...

Comment: Hi Marc, me _again_! I understand if you no longer wish to spend time helping me, If this is the case please just say. I do not want to take advantage of your good nature! I have come a fair way with my app, I have updated the UI taking full advantage of MVVM, and implemented an add language feature. I can add additional resources (rows) to the data and it updates automatically, but I can't get it to update when I attempt to add additional columns. I have implemented the necessary event handlers and the data is correct, the `DataGrid` is just not updating. Could you help for some rep?

Comment: @Killercam, hi again. Have you solved it? If not, I'll have look at it. Just upload the current state again... Cheers.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks very much for getting back to me. I have not yet managed to workout a way around this problem. Once I get this one working I will not trouble you again! I had planned to spend a day on this Sunday. The link to the project is http://sdrv.ms/16EsYci. The problem occurs when I attempt to 'Add Language...' to the main DataGrid, the data behind and the ViewModel are being updated but the dynamic columns that you helped create in your answer above are not updating. I am happy to give you rep for your efforts on one of you other answers... Again, thanks, I hope your well.

Comment: @Killercam Hi! Sorry, I didn't manage to have a look at it yet. Did you solve it in the meantime? I'll have a look at it otherwise..

Comment: Hi Marc, no problem at all, I just really appreciate you looking at it. I have had a play around, adding event handlers to update the `DatGrid` etc. but I have had no luck with it. I think this one is a level above me/my understanding... Thanks again, I have learnt loads from your help... If you want some rep I will set up a question or award one of your existing answers :]

Comment: @Killercam: I've had a look at it. The interface looks nice, good job. I've changed the ResourceDataGrid slightly to update when the according event on the strategy is raised. You should tune this a bit: Currently, it is not handled which resource has changed, for example, so it might be a little inefficient. I hope it helps for now. Let me know. Cheers! : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14429255/ResourceStudio_revMarc.zip

Comment: Thanks very much Marc. I will study what you have done an test over the weekend. Massively appreciated...

Comment: Yes it did Marc. You have taught me a great deal for which I am indebted to you! Thanks again...

Comment: @Killercam Good to hear that, you're welcome. Good luck with your project! Cheers, Marc

Comment: quick question. I am attempting to implement an undo facility and it is going well. However, I can't seem to be able to locate where items contained in the custom `DataGrid` (`ResourceDataGrid`) get set - only the get operation for the bound collection seems to get fired. The value is indeed updated but I am lost as to how this actually occurs as I can pick up when it happens. The bindings work fine - lost is an understatement. If I ask a question can you take a look at it? I will provide rep... :]

Comment: Thanks Marc. I have come along way with the code and it looks great. The following link though is for the last code you posted me back as it was happening there too... http://sdrv.ms/14PNYim 'ResourceStudio130809.zip'. The problem is that if you change cells values for the 2nd and 3rd columns the OnPropertyChanged event is raised. But if you change the dynamic columns that you have designed, the actual value is changed in the bound collection, but no `set` seems to be called what-so-ever; how are the values updated and how can I get a value changed event to be raised?

Comment: To fix this for now I have added an `AttachedCommand` to the `CellEditEnding` event and this works well enough but I am confused as to how the values are being updated. Again, thanks for your time...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a out of the box solution for your problem and your grid columns will have to be created manually. In my case I do it when my `DataGrid` is loaded. I worked on assumption that number of columns is fixed for each element, 10 in my example, and that they are in correct order:

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
   dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
   DataGridTextColumn resourceName = new DataGridTextColumn();
   resourceName.Header = "Name";
   resourceName.Binding = new Binding("ResourceName");
   dataGrid.Columns.Add(resourceName);
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       var resourceColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
       resourceColumn.Header = "Resource " + i;
       resourceColumn.Binding = new Binding(String.Format("ResourceStringList[{0}]", i)) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
       dataGrid.Columns.Add(resourceColumn);
   }
}
```

here is some simple example on [Dropbox](http://db.tt/NqozmKa9)