# WPF DataGrid Column Becoming Corrupt when using Multi-Selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, rendering

All, I am updating a `StatusBar` based on the number of rows selected in a `DataGrid`. I am doing this using MVVM. The relevant XAML is as follows

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AlternationCount="2" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Extended" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Cultures}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language" Binding="{Binding Language}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="LocalName" Binding="{Binding LocalName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

with the `StatusBar` defined by

```
<StatusBar Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0.4,0.4,-0.4">
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF007ACC" Margin="0,2,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalSelectedCultures}"  Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

I am including this code so that you can see the options I am setting on the `DataGrid`; as I say, the functionaility [upon row selection with the mouse the number of rows selected is updated in the `StatusBar`'s `TextBlock`] is working. For further information on the basic mechanism I am using to do this see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2615487/626442.

Now, as I select many items, I am noticing that that the first column [called 'Code'] is not displaying/rendering correctly (as shown, half of it is cropped off).

[image: Display Error]

I have set `EnableRowVirtualization="False"` otherwise it just plane does not work, but **why now is my first column not rendering correctly and how do I make it render correctly?**

Thanks for your time.

---

*Note. I have attempted to set `EnableColumnVirtualization="False"` but this seems worse!? I have also set both `EnableColumnVirtualization="True"` and `EnableRowVirtualization="True"` and this greatly improves performance and removes the rendering problem. However, this breaks the `StatusBar` updates, it just stops as soon as the view scrolls.*

Comment: Strange indeed. That SO article sounds a little hacky, especially where it says "Be sure to set EnableRowVirtualization=False". I wonder if the selected items binding could be accomplished using an attached property instead? I used one to bind the r/o Columns property to a collection in my VM. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320089/how-do-i-bind-a-wpf-datagrid-to-a-variable-number-of-columns. I wonder if you could adapt that code to work with the selected items?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I actually asked the same question as this (as all searches came up null) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16891938/626442) it was a great solution to binding to a variable number of columns. However, I am not sure what you mean by this suggestion; how do you feel binding to columns can help in this case, or have I miss-understood? Thanks for your time...

Comment: One of the answers in that SO link includes code for an attached property that makes it possible to bind to the `Columns` property (not normally possible, as it's R/O). I thought you might be able to adapt that code to create an attached property that lets you bind to your grid's *SelectedItems* property instead (also R/O, and therefore not normally possible to bind to). If this is feasible, it may be preferable to your current approach to binding (using each row's IsSelected property), as this could be the cause of your strange problem.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will look into it and let you know the outcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at http://grokys.blogspot.fr/2012/02/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iv.html
this should solve your prob, and make your code "cleaner"