# Binding Selected RowCount to TextBlock not Firing OnPropertyChanged after DataGrid Scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, rowcount

All, I have recently had a problem where the visuals of a `DataGrid` were not updating when the selected rows were scrolled ([WPF DataGrid Column Becoming Corrupt when using Multi-Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17459832/wpf-datagrid-column-becoming-corrupt-when-using-multi-selection)) which was solved using the method in the linked answer.

I have a `TextBlock` in a `StatusBar` and I bind this to an `IsSelected` property to the required ViewModel. I thought that a solution to the question above would also solve the fact that the selected row count was not being updated correctly; that is, it updates fine when the `DataGrid` scroll bar does not move, but when the bar does move, the `TextBlock` fails to update as the `OnPropertyChanged` event is not fired. I have check lots of posts on this and set the `IsAsync=true` which did help in making the selection correct (it was 1 out before this update). The relevant XMAL is

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" AlternationCount="2" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True"
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Extended" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Cultures, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, IsAsync=True}" 
          dataAccess:MultiSelectItem.IsEnabled="True">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Language" Binding="{Binding Language}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="LocalName" Binding="{Binding LocalName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<StatusBar Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0.4,0.4,-0.4">
    <StatusBarItem DockPanel.Dock="Left" Background="#FF007ACC" Margin="0,2,0,0">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalSelectedCultures}"  Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White"/>
    </StatusBarItem>
</StatusBar>
```

Where the view model that this links to is

```
public class CultureDataViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public enum FilterType
    {
      AllCultures,
      NeutralCultures,
      SpecificCultures
    };
    public FilterType SelectedFilterType { get; private set; }
    public ICollectionView CulturesView { get; private set; }
    public MultiSelectCollectionView<CultureViewModel> Cultures { get; private set; }

    public CultureDataViewModel()
    {
        SelectedFilterType = FilterType.AllCultures;
        LoadCultures();
    }

    void OnCultureViewModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string IsSelected = "IsSelected";
        (sender as CultureViewModel).VerifyPropertyName(IsSelected);
        if (e.PropertyName == IsSelected)
            this.OnPropertyChanged("TotalSelectedCultures");
    }

    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (CultureViewModel cultVm in e.NewItems)
                cultVm.PropertyChanged += this.OnCultureViewModelPropertyChanged;

        if (e.OldItems != null && e.OldItems.Count != 0)
            foreach (CultureViewModel cultVm in e.OldItems)
                cultVm.PropertyChanged -= this.OnCultureViewModelPropertyChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load the avalible cultures depending on filter selection
    /// </summary>
    public void LoadCultures()
    {
        // Get data...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hold the current total selected cultures to add to the resource 
    /// data set.
    /// </summary>
    public string TotalSelectedCultures
    {
        get
        {
            int selectedCultures = this.Cultures.SelectedItems.Count;
            return String.Format("{0:n0} of {1:n0} cultures selected",
                                        selectedCultures,
                                        Cultures.Count);
        }
    }
}
```

**`TotalSelectedCultures` stops updating when the `DataGrid` scrolls, how do I stop this and allow the row count to display even in this case?**

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply attach to the SelectedItems.CollectionChanged event inside LoadCultures()?

```
Cultures.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += SelectedItems_CollectionChanged;

void SelectedItems_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("TotalSelectedCultures");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further? In this case, the viewmodel listens to (its own viewmodel collection Cultures) SelectedItems property (already bound in your view), and simply announces TotalSelectedCultures has changed - which will force any views bound to this property to update.