# Questions on MEF strategy and structure

Tags: .net, prism, mef, composition, modularity

I am tasked with modularizing a C# app that is a rewrite of a very large Delphi app (the DB has 249 tables!). Business constraints proscribe a complete redesign for .NET and better overall architecture, so we are basically just incrementally rewriting module for module of the Delphi app in C#. Until finished, the suite will comprise a mixture of pending rewrites, and C# app modules I want to integrate using MEF.

The app concerns itself with Time-and-Attendance and Access-Control, and has diverse business areas like 'Employee Leave' and 'Visitors'. I think these should be separate projects, where we can swap out a rewritten C# project, and it will be imported into the MEF container. Each project will export an `IBusinessArea`, as a highest level definition, then these will export standard, shared interfaces like `IService`, that introduce the services available in a business area, like `CreateEmployee`. Each service will be a class, in order to standardise the interface of the service with the container, and contain service metadata, such as a `Command` for the service, data on who may use the service, etc.

Am I heading in the right direction, and if so, how do I store and expose `IBusinessArea` and `IService` metadata as classes, versus legions of untyped metadata attributes?

Answer (score 4):

So far, everything you say sounds reasonable to me. You modularize certain areas, define interfaces on different levels of abstraction and export each of your modules with different interfaces, i.e. each module will be registered as several interfaces it implements. You'll be able to resolve your modules according to the level of abstraction you require, get all services, all business areas, etc. So, in my opinion you are heading in the right direction.

How to deal with metadata? MEF provides exporting of metadata, which would appear to be a reasonable thing to use. Maybe I didn't get it entirely, but I have made really bad experiences with MEF metadata export. As far as I can recall, MEF stores metadata as key-value pairs, where the key is a string.

Even if you use the typed metadata export and usage functions, the metadata is not really typesafe. Say you have an interface 'IMetadata' with a property called 'PropertyA' and you register a type (lets call it `Foo` for the sake of creativity) which is decorated with an according attribute in a, what MEF calls *typesafe*, manner (metadata implementing IMetadata). Now suppose you have a second metadata interface 'IMetadataB' which also has a property called `PropertyA`. If you now request resolving `Foo` with metadata `IMetadataB` you'll get the instance you registered in the first place because MEF is satisfied with `PropertyA` being existent in the metadata key-value pairs and builds an according proxy metadata type which implements `IMetadataB`.

Long story short, maybe I'm being unfair to MEF, but I stopped using the MEF built in metadata support and would recommend you to do the same.

As I'm dealing with very complex and lengthy metadata, including kind of documentations of classes which I want to be tightly coupled to the classes I export, I developed a system which works really well for me, although it is a little bit unconventional:

Basically, I define an interface and a baseclass for my metadata, say `MetadataBase` with a string property called `Description`.

```
public class MetadataBase : IMetadata
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards, for every class I want to have metadata for, I derive a class (`FooMetadata`) from this base class and define it partially in XAML. Then, in XAML, I define the class specific value of the property, for example:

```
<md:MetadataBase.Description>
    The description of my class goes here
</md:MetadataBase.Description>
```

With a custom attribute, I relate the metadata type to my actual class:

```
[Export(typeof(IFoo))]
[AssociatedMetadata(typeof(FooMetadata))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    // Whatever
}
```

An extension method for objects lets you read the metadata via reflection:

```
public static IMetadata GetMetadata(this object objectWithMetadata)
{
     // Read attribute type
     // Create instance of the metadata type, i.e. FooMetadata
     // A caching mechanism can be implemented, if needed, but, honestly,
     // my really big metadata objects including images and stuff like this
     // are created within 3-5 ms
     // Return this instance
}
```

Now, you're basically there, you can read the metadata of any object which has metadata like this:

```
var myObjectsMetadata = myObject.GetMetadata();
```

You can utilize this metadata in MEF when you make your `AssociatedMetadataAttribute` implement an interface and register your types with metadata of this interface. Nothing will get mixed up, because you have one type of metadata for everything which holds one property and nothing else (the type).

This solution is not the right way to go for everything, but I love it and your question is a good occasion to present it. Hope it helps!

Comment: To me the most powerful feature of MEF Export Metadata is the fact that you can access them without creating the exported part. For add-in scenarios this is very useful. The points you make about type-safety are valid and should be made clear in the documenation of MEF so that newcomers have an easier time. That said one or two metadata classes should be enough for most applications. If I am not mistaken, your approach is using one, IMetadata. I am not experienced in WPF though and can't tell if your approach can be replaced with MEF Export Metadata.

Comment: @PanosRontogiannis, Correct, I'm using one metadata interface. You can still export the metadata through MEF and access it without actualy resolving the exported part. For me, it's the best of both worlds.